# convert type 'ILNumerics.ILArray<float>' to 'float[*,*]'

Tags: ilnumerics

```
ILArray<float> W_wimgr = new float[256, 256];
float[,] ResultantImage = new float[256, 256];
```

When i Do this

```
ResultantImage = W_wimgr;
```

I got the Error :

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'ILNumerics.ILArray<float>' to 'float[*,*]'
```

Comment: Implicit conversion this way is not supported. You will have to copy the content manually.

Comment: Can you please provide me the code snippet to do so .. I am stucked here.